# How to use rdflib to represent Geometrical points in RDF data?

Tags: rdf, rdfs, rdflib, openlink-virtuoso

I am using [`rdflib`](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro_to_parsing.html) to convert text files into n3 files for the purpose of saving bus station locations ([GTFS](https://gtfs.org/reference/static#stopstxt)).For example if we had `latitude=8.0`, `longitude=5.0`, the literal would be:

`"POINT(5.0 8.0)"^^<http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/virtrdf#Geometry>`

Right now my code (for every line that I read from a text file) looks like this. I am simply saving the latitude, longitude as `float` `xsd` datatypes. We are adding each row in a `graph(g)`.

```
data = fd.readline()
        data = re.split(',', data)

        row = {
          "stop_id": data[0] ,
          "stop_code": data[1] ,
          "stop_name": data[2].replace('"', '') ,
          "stop_desc": data[3] ,
          "stop_lat": data[4] ,
          "stop_lon": data[5] ,
          "location_type": data[6]
        }

        # Create a node for our movie
        stop_node = n['Stop/' + row['stop_id']] # Unique URI
        class_node = n['Stop']
        g.add((stop_node, n.HasStopId, Literal(row['stop_id'],datatype=XSD.int)))
        g.add((stop_node, n.HasStopCode, Literal(row['stop_code'],datatype=XSD.int)))
        g.add((stop_node, n.HasStopName , Literal(row['stop_name'],datatype=XSD.string)))
        g.add((stop_node, n.HasStopDesc, Literal(row['stop_desc'],  datatype=XSD.string)))
        g.add((stop_node, n.HasStopLat, Literal(row['stop_lat'], datatype=XSD.float)))
        g.add((stop_node, n.HasStopLon, Literal(row['stop_lon'], datatype=XSD.float)))
        g.add((stop_node, n.HasLocationType, Literal(row['location_type'], datatype=XSD.int)))
        g.add((stop_node, RDF.type, class_node))
```

**Output example:**

```
@prefix ns1: <http://www.stops.org/> .//I have defined that in another file, not important
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

<http://www.stops.org/Stop/01034> a ns1:Stop ;
    ns1:HasLocationType "0"^^xsd:int ;
    ns1:HasStopCode "10001"^^xsd:int ;
    ns1:HasStopDesc "Outside National Hospital"^^xsd:string ;
    ns1:HasStopId "01034"^^xsd:int ;
    ns1:HasStopLat "8.0"^^xsd:float ;
    ns1:HasStopLon "5.0"^^xsd:float ;
    ns1:HasStopName "turn hospital"^^xsd:string .
```

I have been instructed in case I use OpenLink Virtuoso to import my n3 files into its database. I can find [examples](http://linkedgeodata.org/OSM) on how linkedgeodata uses this representation to query on the data. I haven't understood exactly whether I should first save it as it (two float values) and then [convert it](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparqlgeospat/) into a geometric point in OpenLink Virtuoso or whether I would convert the values as geometric points in the `n3` file that Python produces with `rdflib`. I can't find anything else related on the internet.

Comment: `"POINT(5.0 8.0)”^^<http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/virtrdf#Geometry>` is an RDF literal. You have to use the lexical form `POINT(5.0 8.0)` and simply use the datatype `http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/virtrdf#Geometry`, i.e. you have to create the datatype first and use it instead of the predefined XSD vocab. So it's `Literal('POINT(5.0 8.0)', URIRef('http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/virtrdf#Geometry'))`

Comment: Thank you.Post your comment as an answer if you want so other people can vote on it.